# Springboot 2.3.1.RELEASE and Cassandra connectivity issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

I am getting authentication exception while connecting to CASSANDRA using latest springboot version.
It was working with order version . In newer version of data-cassandra a lot of changes has been introduced . Please find the below configurations I am using .

Springboot version : 2.3.1.RELEASE

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Cassandra Config:

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableCassandraRepositories
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

```
@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contact-points}")
private String contactPoints;

@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.port}")
private int port;

@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
private String keySpace;

@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.password}")
private String password;




@Override
protected String getContactPoints() {
    return contactPoints;
}

@Override
protected int getPort() {
    return port;
}

@Override
protected CqlSession getRequiredSession() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    
    List<InetSocketAddress> hostList = new ArrayList<>();
    Stream.of(contactPoints.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(host->
        hostList.add(new InetSocketAddress(host, port))
    );
    
    
    return CqlSession.builder()
    .addContactPoints(hostList)
    .withAuthCredentials(username, password)
    .withKeyspace(keySpace)
    .withLocalDatacenter("local")
    .build();
}


@Override
protected String getKeyspaceName() {
    return keySpace;
}
```

}

Getting the below error at startup

`requires authenti cation (org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator), but no authenticator configured at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler$InitRequest.lambda$buildAuthenticator$5(ProtocolInitHandler.java:354) at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler$InitRequest.buildAuthenticator(ProtocolInitHandler.java:350) at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ProtocolInitHandler$InitRequest.onResponse(ProtocolInitHandler.java:204) at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.ChannelHandlerRequest.onResponse(ChannelHandlerRequest.java:94) at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.channel.InFlightHandler.channelRead(InFlightHandler.java:255) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

It was working perfectly with Springboot version 2.2.4.RELEASE version

Comment: somebody finally configured authentication on Cassandra nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I remove all the custom configuration class and kept only the below configuration in application.yml and it worked .

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  data:
    cassandra:
      keyspace-name: 
      contact-points: 
      port: 
      username: 
      password: 
      localDatacenter:
```

My repo looks like below :

```
@Repository
 public interface MyRepo extends CassandraRepository<MyEntity,String>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably hitting [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21487), although the issue is marked solved in 2.3.1. Try maybe with 2.4.0, or try the following workaround:

```
@Bean
CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer authCustomizer(CassandraProperties properties) {
    return (builder) -> builder.withAuthCredentials(
        properties.getUsername(), properties.getPassword());
}
```

Comment: Same issue :  requires authenti
cation (com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator), but no authenticator configured